# Showing notification from server directly in app

Tags: android, push-notification

Android push notification show notification in title bar.But i want notification to be directly shown in the app if the app is opened.For example in driving apps when customer request for cabs, notification is directly shown in the driver app which is opened.Driver don't need to refresh the app or click on any link.How can i do that?Should i use push notification only?

Comment: You can use Receiver or Eventbus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its upto you how you want to use the data you get from the GCM.In a typical case you get the data from the GCM server which invoke your Broadcast receiver and which starts the service where you parse the data and then create a notification and show it.If you don't want to create a notification just parse the data and populate the view and show it wherever you want in the current activity or somewhere else.Its entirely upto you how you want to implement it,there are many ways to implement it